# Problema github [Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket #1]

Tags: github, npm

He tenido algunos problemas con github, me sale un error: Got allows a redirect to a UNIX socket #1
y aparece como si fuera una 'vulnerabilidad', debido a esto creo que tampoco puedo visualizar mi pagina en github pages. Soy novato así que bueno espero que puedan darme una mano: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

`"dependencies": { "got": ">=11.8.5" }`

---

`"devDependencies": { "got": ">=11.8.5" }`

La última versión es la 12.1.0